# php back button which skip submit pages

Tags: php

I'm having a bit of trubles doing a simple function.

I have this kind of structure:

- index1.php

-- page1.php

-- page2.php

- index2.php

-- page3.php

[.....]

every pages like *page1.php* has a form. The user come and feed it with required data and submit to *page1.inc.php* which process the data and store them in db. Then a header function bring back him to *page1.php*

The user can submit multiple times and in the history i get (if i submit 2 times):

*page1.php*  >

*page1.inc.php*  >

*page1.php* >

*page1.inc.php* >

*page1.php* >

now in every pages like *page1.php* i have a **back** button and i need that this button redirect directly to his "index father" without pressing it N times.

Is there a better solution then an array where i assign every single page to his index father?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Kindly read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to have better responses to your problem. Share your code, what have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

For this type of navigation breadcrumb might be useful.
You can check out following link for that.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_breadcrumbs.asp

Let me know if you need any help in that.

Comment: yes that could be usefull but i'm looking for something more automatic...

Comment: Ok, I will try to get automatic solution for that